# Serving static files in Sinatra... with beautiful routes?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, static-files

Assuming I have a directory structure similar to:

```
path_to_file/one/index.html
```

How can I set my sinatra app to be routed to

```
mysite.com/path_to_file/one/
```

and have the previously mentioned file to render? `path_to_file` will always stay the same, but there will be different folders (`two`, `three`, etc.) inside it.

I've tried the following:

```
get '/path_to_file/:number' do
  File.read(File.join('path_to_file', "#{params[:number]}", "index.html"))
end
```

but then the e.g. javascript file linked from `index.html` doesn't render correctly.

Comment: What does your Sinatra controller look like?

Comment: not sure what you mean... isn't the code above my Sinatra controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it!

```
get '/path_to_file/:number/:file' do
  File.read(File.join('path_to_file', "#{params[:number]}", "#{params[:file]}"))
end

get '/path_to_file/:number' do
  File.read(File.join('path_to_file', "#{params[:number]}", "index.html"))
end
```

Order is important, since if these two methods are reversed, `get '/path_to_file/:number'` becomes a superset of `get '/path_to_file/:number/:file'`.

Comment: that's what I was thinking in my earlier comment...glad you figured it out! I have done that too in Sinatra.

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought, but you could setup your server software, `Apache`, `nginx`, whatever it is you're using, to serve `.css` and `.js` and image files from a different location.

Comment: Well, it's hosted on Heroku, so I don't have access to the server software. Also, for clarity, I want to keep the custom `.css` and `.js` files in the same folder for other people looking over my code.